# File Upload in asp.net having ERR_content_length_mismatch(chrome) error with ipad

Tags: asp.net, ipad

I have been creating a simple web application that can upload file with ASP.Net.

All of the web application works fine with any browser on a desktop computer. But none of the web application that use file upload(for images) work on the ipad.

Below are the error messages that we get when trying to upload file from the ipad to our web application using the different browsers.

Chrome:
server unexpectedly closed the connection
err_content_length_mismatch

Safari/Firefox:
request body stream exhausted

Any help would greatly be appreciated!